# MVVM with knockout only working in IE

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I am just starting woth Knockout and am following the tutorials. While it works like a charm on IE it does not appear to on any other browser and I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Here is the page markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Text">Text</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="Text" name="Text" data-bind="text:Text"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-1.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout.mapping.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var model = {"Text":"Test Text"};
    ko.applyBindings(model);

</script>
```

Many thanks for any help

### UPDATE

Discovered my error and it was quite simple. Rather than delete the question I will leave it up in case anyone else comes across this.
The problem is IE again ! and the fact that it appear to work in IE makes it seem as though the others are at fault, when, in fact, IE is being a bit lax about interpreting the binding expression.

the line

```
<input type="text" id="Details_CompanyName" name="Details.CompanyName" data-bind="text:Details.CompanyName"/>
```

... sould be

```
<input type="text" id="Details_CompanyName" name="Details.CompanyName" data-bind="value:Details.CompanyName"/>
```

Comment: slightly off topic: you do realize that by using `var model = {"Text":"Test Text"};` you are just doing one-way binding. To ensure that any changes in the input are saved back in `model.Text` , you have to use `var model = {"Text":ko.observable("Test Text")};`

Comment: I find that 9 times out of 10 if something 'works' in IE & not Firefox/Chrome then there is a problem in your HTML/JS. IE is covering your mistake. The other 'more standards based' browsers throw the error as expected.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and mark is as accepted.

Comment: I wish the other browsers would throw some kind of error, I'm having this problem and I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to possibly be a bug?

Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eKWrT/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yU3aK/) for jsFiddle examples of a simple change from  to